# Is that possible to call module factory from other javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two javascript files separately and I want to retrieve one from another. So, I created Module factory as below;

```
 var module = angular.module('test',[]);

 module.factory('$result', function() {
   var data = {something:"somewhere"};
   return data;
 });
```

and I want to called from other file. For now, I settled as below;

```
 var module = angular.module('myApp', ['test']);

  module.controller('NearestController', function($test) {

    console.log(test);

  });
```

Which part of me doing wrong ?? please help me and I'm newbie in angular

Comment: Err, isn't your factory named `$result`?

Comment: `module.controller('NearestController', function($result) { console.log($result.something); });`

Comment: Don't use `$` in names of your services. It's supposed to be only for built-in angular dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be like that ..

```
 var module = angular.module('test',[]);

 module.factory('Result', function() {
   var data = {something:"somewhere"};
   return data;
 });
```

You can call like that.

```
var module = angular.module('myApp', ['test']);

  module.controller('NearestController', function(Result) {

    console.log(Result);

  });
```

Hope it might be work.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments suggested, you inject your dependencies as parameters in your controller function:

```
 var module = angular.module('myApp', ['test']);

  module.controller('NearestController', function($result) {

    console.log(test);

  });
```